# Is it considered a bad practice to replace a built-in key binding in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, conventions

I bind `C-x C-f` to `counsel-find-file` so I replaced the default `find-file` with `counsel-find-file`. Now I would like to bind `counsel-recentf` to see a list of recent files and I would like to bind that to `C-x f` however `C-x f` is used to set fill column. I never set fill column manually and If I do that will be probably in init.el.

My question: is it okay to replace `C-x f` set-fill-column which is an Emacs built-in key binding with `counsel-recentf`?

Comment: The vague recommendation is to use C-c for user bindings, but I don't overriding a key you never use will raise any eyebrows (until you try to use somebody else's Emacs, or somebody tries to use yours).

Comment: Oh then I will map it to `C-c r` that seems to be undefined by default. I would love to be consistent.

Comment: Any `C-c <letter>` is reserved for you to use however you wish.  Refer to https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html

Comment: Personal opinion ahead... I don't care too much about official recommendations. I make Emacs my Emacs. To me, that's part of the story of Emacs. I happily remapped C-v and C-b as prefixes for my own keybindings, because I just need more than would be available with `C-c <letter>`. Works well for me since ca. 20 years or so. You may encounter conflicts every now and then, in particular with org-mode which is heavy on keybindings.

Comment: @tripleee: "The vague recommendation is to use C-c for user bindings". No, there is no such recommendation. All keys are fair game for a user. Keys that start with `C-c` followed by a letter are the only keys *reserved* for users.

Answer (score 0):

Is the binding you want to make for your own use, or is it a binding you set in a library you provide for others?

1. If the former, then **you can make any key bindings you like**. All key bindings are fair game for a user.
2. If the latter then you're requested to follow the GNU Emacs [**key-binding conventions**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html).

(You can read the conventions in Emacs itself, using `C-h i m Elisp RET g Key Binding Conventions`. Or `C-h i m Elisp RET`, followed by `i key-binding, TAB`.)

The conventions exist to facilitate people playing well together - cooperation, consideration. The key-binding conventions *reserve* certain keys for users. That means that libraries should not bind them. It does **not** mean that those are the *only* keys available for users - see #1.

As that doc says:

> Sequences consisting of `C-c` and a letter (either upper or lower case) are
> *reserved for users*; they are the **only** sequences reserved for
> users, so do not block them.